# Linked Matrix Implementation in Python?

Tags: python, list, matrix, linked-list

I know in a linked list there are a head node and a tail node. Well, for my data structures assignment, we are suppose to create a linked matrix with references to a north, south, east, and west node. I am at a loss of how to implement this. A persistent problem that bothers me is the head node and tail node. The user inputs the number of rows and the number of columns. Should I have multiple head nodes then at the beginning of each row and multiple tail nodes at the end of each row? If so, should I store the multiple head/tail nodes in a list?

Thank you.

Comment: A good approach to this is the way many 2-dimensional data structures are implemented from one-dimensional ones -- namely, by having a _container of containers_. Which in this case would be a linked-list of linked-lists. Depending on the exact details of how you implement the 1-D linked-lists, this might require only keeping a reference to the head node of each sub-linked-list. (because, for example, the last node of each list refers back to its head node).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment! I was also considering another approach that involves actually making a matrix containing the nodes itself and then using try/except to see if each node in the matrix contains a neighbor, and, if so, reference it correspondingly. However, using such a matrix defeats the purpose of a linked list, so maybe I can use it as just a scaffolding. After that, I would extract the nodes from the matrix somehow and convert it into a linked list, but that is where I am lost. Thank you for your time also, I'm a beginner at CS and would greatly appreciate further advice.

Comment: A matrix is just an array of arrays (or list of lists). The main difference being that all elements always exist, so random access would be quick and compact. Linked-lists would not be most people's first choice unless there were potentially huge numbers of elements involved and the matrices were often only partially full.

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one way to interpret this, but one option is:

Have a single "head" node at the top-left corner and a "tail" node at the bottom-right. There will then be row-head, row-tail, column-head, and column-tail nodes, but these are all accessible from the overall head and tail, so you don't need to keep track of them, and they're already part of the linked matrix, so they don't need to be part of a separate linked list.

(Of course a function that builds up an RxC matrix of zeroes will probably have local variables representing the current row's head/tail, but that's not a problem.)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what options you want/need to efficiently support.

For instance, a singly linked list with only a head pointer can be a stack (insert and remove at the head).  If you add a tail pointer you can insert at either end, but only remove at the head (stack or queue).  A doubly linked list can support insertion or deletion at either end (deque).  If you try to implement an operation that your data structure is not designed for you incur an O(N) penalty.

So I would start with a single pointer to the (0,0) element and then start working on the operations your instructor asks for.  You may find you need additional pointers, you may not.  My guess would be that you will be fine with a single head pointer.